# How to make dynamically adjustable 3 pane layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create an UI which will allow the user to adjust the layout by dragging it. Unfortunately, I don't have sufficient reputation to add an image to explain what I'm trying to achieve, so here's a schematic.

```
|-----------------|
|   |             |
|P1 |             |
|   |   MapView   |
|---|             |
| P2|             |
|-----------------|
```

This is the overall outline for the layout. P1 and P2 are dragable panels, meaning they should dynamically adjustable. Can anyone give me any pointers on how to go about this?

Comment: You might not be able to post an image, but you should be able to add a link. it's hard to help you with your layout if we don't know what the layout is.

Comment: Very interesting idea. But I think it would be better if you showed what u have attempted till now or at least some research u have done.

Comment: i have created the layout but functionality i dont have any idea how to do it? looking for some suggestions or sample form some one who worked on this.?

Comment: Thanks for your time Franci, i have added the basic view of my requirement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you are a beginner.. this is the method which might help you..

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {   public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
      DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
      view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
      view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }   } }
```

OR

here are the links

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/

Comment: i don't have points to vote, i selected it. thanks for your time.